# PL/SQL Query to get the total of both two columns in a subquery

Tags: plsql, subquery

I have a two subquery below to get the total of same column. Now, I want is to get the total of the two subquery I used. How can I do that?

Subquery1

```
(select sum(aila.total_rec_tax_amount)
from ap_invoice_lines_all aila
where aila.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
and aila.line_type_lookup_code = 'ITEM'
and aila.tax_classification_code = 'VAT12 SERVICES' 
group by aila.invoice_id) as total_tax_charged1
```

Subquery2

```
(select sum(aila.total_rec_tax_amount)
from ap_invoice_lines_all aila
where aila.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
and aila.line_type_lookup_code = 'ITEM'
and aila.tax_classification_code = 'VAT12 GOODS'
group by aila.invoice_id) as total_tax_charged2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Union all and then calculate a sum:

```
select sum( as total_tax_charged)
from(
  select sum(aila.total_rec_tax_amount) as total_tax_charged
  from ap_invoice_lines_all aila
  where aila.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
  and aila.line_type_lookup_code = 'ITEM'
  and aila.tax_classification_code = 'VAT12 SERVICES' 
  group by aila.invoice_id 
Union all
  select sum(aila.total_rec_tax_amount)
  from ap_invoice_lines_all aila
  where aila.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
  and aila.line_type_lookup_code = 'ITEM'
  and aila.tax_classification_code = 'VAT12 GOODS'
  group by aila.invoice_id
)
```

you can also do it with one select statement

```
select sum(aila.total_rec_tax_amount)
from ap_invoice_lines_all aila
where aila.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
and aila.line_type_lookup_code = 'ITEM'
and aila.tax_classification_code in( 'VAT12 SERVICES', 'VAT12 GOODS')
group by aila.invoice_id
```